# How to collect results from maze

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I have build a javascript maze game, with different levels on different pages. I have a script that can time the amount of seconds that it takes for the user to complete the level, and store it in a variable. I would like to collect the times from all the levels and at the end, store the results in a MySQL database. Then, I would like for it to be able to display the results, which I know how to do. What is a practical and efficient way to send all the data to the database at once?

My maze is at http://thomaswd.com/maze. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like local storage would fit nicely to store results of each game and show them on a final page etc, unless you for some reason need to keep the results of every user for some later statistics or something.

Comment: yeah, I need this for a school project, and I need to be able to test five different people and show the results

Comment: I took a look at your maze page. Do you really think it's a good idea to show a message like "WTF is wrong with you?!" to your users? Given that it's a school project we really shouldn't be giving you a complete answer. But a hint, since you seem to be using jQuery already: read a jQuery Ajax tutorial. Also that hideously long `refresh()` function can be reduced to about five lines if you think it through.

Comment: Easiest way then would be to submit a form that you prefill with javascript or do an ajax request to the server and do your thing there.

Comment: @nnnnnn how do I simplify `refresh()` to five lines?

Comment: The "current" td element will be `document.getElementById('td' + alergnon)` (which would return `null` if `alergnon` doesn't refer to a valid element index) so you don't need 48 variables and you don't need the switch statement at all. Maybe seven or eight lines by the time you throw in an `if` statement to handle what is currently in `case 27`.

Answer (score 0):

How about jQuery .post() perhaps with JSON-encoded data?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I'm kinda new to javascript

Comment: you programmed a maze, and you're new to javascript? wow. nice maze by the way

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the method POST to keep some kind of information while going to another page, and the use it at your will